# Using JTable for a JTree cell editor

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtree

I would like to use a JTable for editing a JTree, I extended DefaultTreeCellEditor and implemented isCellEditable getTreeCellEditorComponent, in getTreeCellEditorComponent I return a JTable. Everything works up to this point when a node is edited swing displays the JTable filled with the objects content however when editing is complete, valueForPathChanged of DefaultTreeModel never gets called. If I use a text field for editing which is the default everything works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JTextField` has a [`notifyAction`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html#notifyAction), named "notify-field-accept" and typically bound to `KeyEvent.VK_ENTER`, that signals the `CellEditor` to `stopEditing()` and ultimately invokes  the `DefaultTreeCellEditor` method, [`valueForPathChanged()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultTreeModel.html#valueForPathChanged-javax.swing.tree.TreePath-java.lang.Object-).

It's not clear how you indicate that editing is complete for your `JTable`. You should be able to do something similar with the `JTextField` in a [`CellEditorListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/event/CellEditorListener.html) that is added to your custom editor via [`addCellEditorListener()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractCellEditor.html#addCellEditorListener-javax.swing.event.CellEditorListener-).

Incidentally, [`valueForPathChanged()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultTreeModel.html#valueForPathChanged-javax.swing.tree.TreePath-java.lang.Object-) mentions that "If you use custom user objects in the TreeModel you're going to need to subclass this and set the user object of the changed node to something meaningful."