# How to make  jtable as a node of jtree

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtree

I want to create a jtree with nodes of jtable and that jtable should be editable when I click on a cell.
Please respond ASAP it's important to my project.

Comment: "Please respond ASAP"  Well, I have a complete solution, but (checks watch) it is obviously too late.  Never mind.  (Or to put that another way, mentioning your time constraints actually *decreases* the chance of a quick answer, or *any* answer.)  BTW - that was a fib about having the answer.  ;)

Answer (score 2):

As an alternate design, consider [`JSplitPane`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JSplitPane.html): one pane would hold the `JTree`, while the other displays the `JTable` corresponding to the selected tree node. See [*Responding to Node Selection*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html#select) for details.

Answer (score 1):

You need a custom Renderer / custom Editor. Check out these tutorials:

- one tutorial: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/CreatingaCustomRenderer.htm
- basic swing tutorial on trees: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html
- another swing tutorial, talks about custom editors for tables but trees are similar - http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editor
- Similar question asked here: [Using JTable for a JTree cell editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432218/using-jtable-for-a-jtree-cell-editor)

Try these, let us know if you're still stuck